# Date is getting subtracted by one when posting data into mongo db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mern

When I tried to save a record with the date column into mongodb using ExpressJS, date part alone getting subtracted by one automatically. Not sure why? Please find the schema of my DB and the post router that I'm using below.

Example Input posted in body:

```
{
    "name":"Articulation Exam",
    "location":"IoN Center",
    "timing":"11:00am",
    "date":"06/27/2023",
    "maximum_allowed_participants":100,
    "active_participants":1
}
```

Data stored in DB:

```
{
        "_id": "6485a0737cd0de176a0c87c0",
        "name": "Articulation Exam",
        "location": "IoN Center",
        "timing": "11:00am",
        "date": "2023-06-26T18:30:00.000Z",
        "maximum_allowed_participants": 100,
        "active_participants": 1,
        "createdAt": "2023-06-11T10:22:43.046Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-11T10:22:43.046Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

If you see above examples, I have posted the date as 06/27/2023.But it got stored as 2023-06-26 which is not correct. Please correct, if I'm missing something here.

```
router.route('/post').post((req,res)=>{
    const data = {
        name:req.body.name,
        location:req.body.location,
        timing:req.body.timing,
        date:new Date(req.body.date),
        maximum_allowed_participants:req.body.maximum_allowed_participants,
        active_participants:req.body.active_participants
    }

    const newRecord = new Events(data);

    newRecord.save()
    .then(response=>res.send('A new event "'+response.name+'" has been added Succssfully!'))
    .catch(err=>res.send(err));
})
```

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:3
    },
    location:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:2
    },
    timing:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    maximum_allowed_participants:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    active_participants:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }
},
{
    timestamps:true
});
```

Comment: Please provide an example input and output in order to answer your question.

Comment: TLDR 99% sure: time zone difference between your server and mongoDB driver/server which is causing rollover to previous day when adjusted.

Comment: @Stitt I have added an example too. Please refer.

Comment: @AyushGupta In that case, could you please tell me how to resolve that. I'm developing this web app in laptop only and I'm using local servers.

Comment: `Date` values in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - always and only. Usually the client is responsible to display the date in local format and time zone.

Answer (score 0):

@Ayush Gupta is correct, your issue is due to your server running on UTC time, but your input being on your local time.

This isn't necessarily an issue. Your best option **with the information you have provided** is to only provide interaction with the date (i.e via your front-end) by using the [toLocalTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method. This will remove any complications with users seeing the date incorrectly. If you require a different use case, please provide details.

Comment: When I use this method, I end up in type cast error. Please find the error message below.

"name": "CastError",
 "message": "Cast to date failed for value \"16/6/2023, 12:00:00 am\" (type string) at path \"date\""

Comment: @Gokul what are you actually trying to do with this date prop?

Comment: My actual requirement is to create a event manager application. That date column stores when the event took place. Due to this issue, I'm not proceed further.

Comment: The date column is always going to be stored in UTC time. As I mentioned, you will need to have your client-side application convert this to the appropriate local time. Ensure that you are retrieving it from your database as a date object.